# ipysheet and dataframe. How modify value in a ipysheet when a checkbox is checked

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter, jupyter-lab

Need your help.
I create a dataframe and load it as ipysheet.
I overload the column "1" with checkbox.
Purpose: When I click on a checkbox of a cell of the column 1, I multiplicate the corresponding value in the column "2" by two. (not all the column 2)

I tried different things but it doesn't work as expected.
cf code below

- So first how to get the value from the ipysheet of the column "2".
  Something like that but I don't want to overload the datas. i just want to get the existing values.
  `#column2 = ipysheet.column(1,[x for x in range(2)])`
- How to change a value of an element in the second column when I check something in the first column ?

Thanks for your help,

## Code to reproduce:

```
import numpy as np
from ipywidgets import Checkbox
import pandas as pd
import ipysheet
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 2], [4, 5]]))

wsMultiple = ipysheet.sheet(ipysheet.from_dataframe(df))
column1 = ipysheet.column(0,[Checkbox() for _ in range(2)])
#column2 =  ?

def test(change):
print("test")
#something like:
#column2.value = column2.value * 2

column1.observe(test, "value")
wsMultiple`
```

**Before:**

> 0          1
> 0  checkbox   2
> 1  checkbox   5

**After** the click on the second checkbox:

> 0          1
> 0  checkbox   2
> 1  checkbox   10

Answer (score 4):

Your column contains a list of `Checkbox` widgets so the `column1.value` attribute actually never changes.

For example when clicking the first checkbox the `column1.value[0].value` changed to `True`, but not the `column1.value`. So your `test` function is never called here. You would need to listen on changes for each checkbox separately... But there might be a simpler way.

ipysheet already provides means to render checkboxes when values are booleans, so no need to create `Checkbox` widgets manually. If you provide a list of booleans directly, this time your event will be triggered.

You can try something like:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import ipysheet
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 2], [4, 5]]))

wsMultiple = ipysheet.sheet(ipysheet.from_dataframe(df))

# Here wsMultiple.cells is a list of cell-range, those cell-ranges are actually the sheet columns. 
# So you can override the first column like that: 
column1 = ipysheet.column(0, [False, False])  # New column
column2 = wsMultiple.cells[1]                 # Keep the "old" second column

wsMultiple.cells = (column1, column2) # override all the columns

# Keep a reference to the original values
original_values = column2.value

def test(*args, **kwargs):
    # Here is the logic for multiplying by two if the first column is checked, there might be more optimized ways of doing it 
    column2.value = [
        x*2 if column1.value[idx] else x
        for idx, x in enumerate(original_values)
    ]

column1.observe(test, "value")
wsMultiple
```

Although I do not recommend it, it may be cleaner if your dataframe already contains booleans on the first column, instead of having to override it.

Comment: Thanks a lot Martin !! You helped a lot and it is very clear now.

Comment: Happy to help! Do you mind selecting my answer as being the right one?

Comment: Hi  Martin,
"column1" contains a list of checkbox. But I can't find the attribute disabled. 
So I tried to overload the type checkbox like below:
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import ipysheet
import ipywidgets as widgets

wcheckbox = widgets.Checkbox

df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 2 ], [4, 5],[6,7]]))

df['checkbox'] = False
    
wsMultiple = ipysheet.sheet(ipysheet.from_dataframe(df))
columncheckbox = ipysheet.column(2,[wcheckbox(value=x) for idx, x in enumerate(df['checkbox'])])

columncheckbox.value[0].disabled = True
But the checkbox are not center. Any idea?

Comment: It is not possible with ipysheet. If you want this feature you need to use Checkbox widgets.

Comment: I misread your comment (reading unindented code is quite painful IMHO). If you want to center the checkboxes you need to play a bit with the CSS. You can achieve that by tweaking the `layout` attribute of the checkboxes, see https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/Widget%20Styling.html

Comment: The problem of the space before the checkbox was lalready mentionned here:
https://github.com/jupyter-widgets/ipywidgets/issues/1758

Comment: What I find interesting about this answer is that you need to replace the cells in the spreadsheet on this line: `wsMultiple.cells = (column1, column2) # override all the columns` I would have expected the returned object to be the same as the one in the sheet.